# Second derivative $= 0$ at turning point $(0,0)$ for $y = x^5-5x^4$

Tags: derivatives, stationary-point

My understanding is that at a maximum turning point of a function the first derivative is zero and the second derivative is negative. However, I'm confused that with $y = x^5-5x^4$ the turning point $(0,0)$ has a second derivative of $0$ instead of a negative value. I feel I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: $x^5$ is too much; think of $x^3$. What kind of special point does it have at $x=0$?

Comment: It is a horizontal point of inflexion, but for the curve in question even though it is a maximum turning point at x=0 the second derivative is not negative which confuses me

Comment: At a local maximum/minimum, the first derivative is zero and the second is necessarily non-positive /non-negative. **If** at a point where the first derivative is zero the second is negative/positive, then you have a maximum/minimum. Necessary conditions are not the same as sufficient conditions.

Comment: @GReyes thank you, so interpreting this means that there can be a point where the first derivative is zero and it is a local maximum or minimum even when the second derivative is zero ?

Comment: You see yourself that it can. If the example is still too complicated, think of $x^4$: it obviously has a minimum, but...

Comment: Thank you so much for making this clear. I haven’t learned the necessary and sufficient conditions but I’m looking forward to doing so when I get to university!

Comment: You don't need to wait for university. The necessary and sufficient condition for a function $f(x)$ to have a local maximum at $x = a$ is for $f(x) \le f(a)$ for every $x$ in some open interval $(b,c)$ with $b < a < c$. Derivatives are not necessary, but are useful in finding the point when they exist. As a general rule, if a function is $k$ times differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a)$ through $f^{(k-1)}(a)$ are all $0$, then $a$ is a local minimum if $f^{(k)}(a) > 0$ and a local maximum if $f^{(k)}(a) < 0$. If $f^{(k)} = 0$ as well, you must investigate by other means.

Comment: @PaulSinclair What you said only works for _even_ $k$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - true. I was a bit too hasty when composing it.